# Шифрование большого объёма информации

Tags: python, python-3.x, шифрование

Мне необходимо шифровать по алгоритму aes (желательно с помощью модуля fernet) файл неопределённого объёма. Базовые функции fernet прекрасно справляются с небольшими картинками, но с большим файлом размером примерно 600мб - нет. Сначала компьютер зависает на какое-то время, а потом программа, которая шифрует файл, вылетает.

Каким образом можно зашифровать большой файл с помощью python?

Comment: А сколько памяти на компе? А система 64-битная?

Comment: Вот эта штука вроде позволяет в потоковом режиме шифровать: https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/

Comment: Можно руками нарезать файл по кусочкам (считывать байтами по блокам) и шифровать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать, например, модуль [pyAesCrypt](https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/), который позволяет указать размер буфера при шифровании файла:

```
pyAesCrypt.encryptFile("data.txt", "data.txt.aes", password, bufferSize)
```

Либо вообще проводить шифрование в потоковом режиме:

```
with open("data.txt", "rb") as fIn:
    with open("data.txt.aes", "wb") as fOut:
        pyAesCrypt.encryptStream(fIn, fOut, password, bufferSize)
```

При таком подходе проблем с памятью на больших файлах быть не должно.

Comment: Можно, кст, в одном блоке `with` через запятую: `with open("data.txt", "rb") as fIn, open("data.txt.aes", "wb") as fOut:` :) Отпуск? ;)

Comment: @gil9red Это цитата из кода по ссылке! Мопед не мой! ))

Comment: А можно каким-то образом зашифровать в переменную, а не в файл? Ну то есть не сохранять на диске, а лишь получить во время выполнения программы?

Comment: @coder8008 Вы по ссылке не ходили? Там в конце именно такой пример: "you can also perform in-memory encryption/decryption (using BytesIO):"

Comment: Точно, спасибо.